# Create a codemod to add a new element to array

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, jscodeshift

I have been struggling to adding a new object to array of objects with `jscodeshift`. My problem is I can't figure out how I have to query an array after I got `VariableDeclarator`. I need to get a last element in the array after that I can insert a new node. Here is the code:

```
export default function transformer(file, api) {

    const j = api.jscodeshift;
    const root = j(file.source);
    const changeList = root.find(j.VariableDeclarator, {
        id: {name: 'list'},
    }).closest(j.ArrayExpression, {
        elements: [""]
    }).replaceWith(p => {
        console.log(p);
    }).toSource();

};
```

I am playing with it on [AST explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/09d8bc395f64894b5f03c29cc6fc22ca/6c2a9b724de3783d6c77af5da7f71ce804b275d7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.closest` returns the closest *ancestor* node matching the type. The `ArrayExpression` is a *descendant* though, so you have to use `.find` again. This works:

```
export default function transformer(file, api) {

  // import jscodeshift
    const j = api.jscodeshift;
    // get source code 

    const root = j(file.source);
    // find a node

    return root.find(j.VariableDeclarator, {id: {name: 'list'}})
    .find(j.ArrayExpression)
    .forEach(p => p.get('elements').push(j.template.expression`x`))
    .toSource();
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer)